# Polygonizing slope raster when output shapefile is more than 4 Gb?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile

I am trying to polygonize a slope raster using Grass's r.to.vect command.
The command starts but ends up crashing because the output shapefile is more than 4 Gb.

How could I get multiple shapefiles out?

I work on QGIS 3.4 and Windows 8.1

Answer (score 5):

Either choose a different file format or partition the raster into smaller pieces until each one produces a shapefile which weighs less than 4GB.

You can partition the raster automatically by selecting the "Create VRT" checkbox at the top and specifiying the tile sizes in the section that appears (see pic)

[image]

In my personal opinion, however, it is better to just choose a different file format, because shapefiles are old and come with more limitations than just file size. Read more about it here: http://switchfromshapefile.org/